# Android app. redirection from android phone browser link

Tags: javascript, android, html

I want to call android application on clicking of button on some website from mobile.

For example,
When I click the web link, its call to android application if installed. Otherwise its redirect to specific application download on Android Market place.

Thanks in advance.
G. Padmanabhan.

Comment: Its already been asked I guess try this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement an Intent Filter. Read the documentation at the following link:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html#ifs